# Some guidance if possible? Cloning records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Very new to RoR and am working on a music app where a release can have many products. Until now I've been working away with a master 'release' level, with 'product' variant levels and 'track' levels below that.

I'm now thinking this might not be the optimal approach and am now considering a much simpler single table approach where I can clone entries to create the product variants. (My initial approach presents some serious issues in terms of importing the catalog of almost 10,000 lines currently stored in a single excel table).

In my head, the requirements would be as follows:

- Create Record (this is the easy bit)
- Create a clone of any record (and it's tracklisting) minus unique fields such as Cat_No/Barcode and concurrently create an association somewhere so variants can be combined in release views, admin sales reports etc.
- Ability to update certain common fields like artist, title, description (to avoid having to edit each clone)
- Ability to update / override certain cloned fields that in most cases will be the same, but may occasionally differ; release date for example.

Any guidance offered would be MASSIVELY appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this functionality should be implemented in the model that is to be cloned and the logic you describe should be applied internally.  I didn't understand what you meant by concurrently creating associations somewhere so variants can be combined in release views...., so I didn't answer that.

For instance:

```rb
def clone(new_attributes = {})
    source_attributes = self.attributes
    source_attributes.delete :cat_no #unique attributes
    source_attributes.delete :barcode 
    merged_attributes = source_attributes.merge new_attributes 
    MyModel.new(merged_attributes);      

end

def clone!(new_attributes = {})
    copy = self.clone(new_attributes)
    copy.save!
    copy.reload
    copy
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll see how I get on with this. Just to double check, this should go into the model, not the controller?

Oh, what I meant by concurrently creating associations somewhere so variants can be combined in release views is that I want some what to track that cloned records are related. For example, I set up the CD, clone the record to set up the LP version and then clone again to set up the Download version........i'd then want to be able to combine the three in certain views / reporting etc.

Thanks again.

Comment: I've been playing around with creating clones in the console and clone doesn't seem to work where dup does. Any reason for that and not to use dup instead of clone?

Comment: In Rails 3.1 Cloning is shallow: "attributes only"
Where dup is deep: "relationships" too.

The fundamental question is which do you want or do you want something in-between, which basically means you'll have to implement it.